# Amazon S3(AWS) in magento programmatically

Tags: magento-1.9, database, product-images, media, amazon-web-services

i'm adding product programmatically in magento store(Magento ver. 1.9.0.1).

I want to display and save images On my store from Amazon S3(AWS) in magento (Frontend & BackEnd),

i'm using this extension: https://github.com/arkadedigital/magento-s3.

**my issue is i have no idea how to add Amazon S3 image to magento db programmatically.**

**it is possible then how?**

Any help or suggestion will be appreciated.

Comment: Did you check out this extension for amazon s3? https://magecomp.com/magento-amazon-s3.html

Answer (score 1):

Hi you can call all media folder from Amazon s3 Follow below tutorial and let me know

https://www.thirdandgrove.com/integrating-magento-with-amazons-cdn-cloudfront

and for full media url you can do like this

`$media_url =  Mage::getBaseUrl(Mage_Core_Model_Store::URL_TYPE_MEDIA);`

and for Your method try this

`->addImageToMediaGallery("$media_url/media/catalog/product/1/0/10243-1.png", array('image','thumbnail','small_image'), false, false)`

I am not 100% sure its working or not but you can try and let me know

Comment: Thanks for Answer, i did this but my problem is how to add Amazon S3(AWS) in magento database programmatically.im using this http://inchoo.net/magento/programming-magento/programatically-manually-creating-simple-magento-product/

Comment: So you have a problem with `->addImageToMediaGallery` this function?? itis taking magento base url instead cdn url Am I right??

Comment: yes, you are right.its use store image in Media.in db its store /folde/folder/image.jpg path .

Comment: so what is your worry when magento fetches its first search on cdn and then if is is not find then check on local

Comment: i have in insert image path into magento db.it is  possible with programmatically?

Comment: check my updated answer

Comment: its give 'Image does not exist' Exception.addImageToMediaGallery is not able to get image from https://bots-products.s3.amazonaws.com/badger/images/002207CARDNLS.jpg

Comment: I think Your cdn media file directory does not have write permission to for data that is why you are facing this issue